# How to pass a key value to a .map function

Tags: javascript

Just wondering if someone can explain this to me: I've managed to achieve the result I'm after, by manually declaring the '`key`' within the map `function`.

I'm struggling to understand how I pass the key within the map functions so I can easily call `valueMapper('key')` in order to get the same result (examples below).

I've uncovered a few solutions, but none of them seem to make sense. Please add some background to the method, I'm more interested in the process than the solution.

Thanks for the help!

```
var users = [
  {firstName: 'Pete', lastName: 'Barrat', favoriteFood: 'Pizza', age: 30},
  {firstName: 'Lisa', lastName: 'Jenkins', favoriteFood: 'Curry', age: 34},
  {firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Yates', favoriteFood: 'Fish', age: 54},
  {firstName: 'Claire', lastName: 'Smith', favoriteFood: 'Steak', age: 21},
  {firstName: 'Adam', lastName: 'Johnson', favoriteFood: 'Pasta', age: 27}
 ]

// write a function call valueMapper
// valueMapper takes one argument which is the name of a key 
// it returns an array of all the values in the users array that correspond to that key
// examples: 

// valueMapper('favoriteFood')
// -> ['Pizza', 'Curry', 'Fish', 'Steak', 'Pizza']

// valueMapper('firstName')
// -> ['Pete', 'Lisa', 'Bob', 'Claire', 'Adam']


/* #1st solution, I managed to get the answers I'm looking for, but I haven't defined
the valueMapper function and I haven't passed it a key yet */

var lastName = users.map(function(users) {
    return users['lastName'];
 })

 console.log(lastName);



/* #2nd solution is an attempt to create an anonymous function so that
I can pass through a key to the function in order to read the same results*/


function valueMapper() {Object.keys(users).map(function(key) {
   return users[key];
});
}

console.log(valueMapper('firstName'));
```

Comment: `const valueMapper = (arr, key) => arr.filter(i => i.hasOwnProperty(key)).map(i => i[key]); valueMapper(users, 'favoriteFood');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you naming a function (`valueMapper`), then it is not an anonymous function.
2. You don't need to iterate over the Properties using `Object.Keys` as you are passing the property value as an argument to your function. However, As a gaurd you can check if the passed in property name matches the existing properties on the object.

   You might be looking for a solution like as shown below.

```js
var users = [
  {firstName: 'Pete', lastName: 'Barrat', favoriteFood: 'Pizza', age: 30},
  {firstName: 'Lisa', lastName: 'Jenkins', favoriteFood: 'Curry', age: 34},
  {firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Yates', favoriteFood: 'Fish', age: 54},
  {firstName: 'Claire', lastName: 'Smith', favoriteFood: 'Steak', age: 21},
  {firstName: 'Adam', lastName: 'Johnson', favoriteFood: 'Pasta', age: 27}
 ]

// write a function call valueMapper
// valueMapper takes one argument which is the name of a key 
// it returns an array of all the values in the users array that correspond to that key
// examples: 

// valueMapper('favoriteFood')
// -> ['Pizza', 'Curry', 'Fish', 'Steak', 'Pizza']

// valueMapper('firstName')
// -> ['Pete', 'Lisa', 'Bob', 'Claire', 'Adam']


/* #1st solution, I managed to get the answers I'm looking for, but I haven't defined
the valueMapper function and I haven't passed it a key yet */

var lastName = users.map(function(users) {
    return users['lastName'];
 })

 console.log(lastName);



/* #2nd solution is an attempt to create an anonymous function so that
I can pass through a key to the function in order to read the same results*/


function valueMapper(passedInKey) {
  
 return users.map(function(user) {
   if(user.hasOwnProperty(passedInKey)){     
    return user[passedInKey];
   }
});
}

console.log(valueMapper('firstName'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Most of the other solutions worked, but this was more in line with my current level of understanding. Thanks for chipping in.

Answer (score 2):

When you `map` an array with function `fn`, you are creating a new array that contains the results of calling `fn` on each item in that array.

```
[a, b, c].map(fn)  // => [fn(a), fn(b), fn(c)]

// e.g.
[1.5, 2.2, 0.3].map(Math.floor)  // => [1, 2, 0]
```

The functionality you're looking for exists in popular JavaScript libraries, and is sometimes called `pluck`. It uses mapping to "pluck" a field from each object in a collection:

```
var pluck = function (collection, field) {
    return collection.map(function (item) {
        return item[field];
    });
};

// e.g.
var albums = [
    { title: 'Colony', release: '1999' },
    { title: 'Clayman', release: '2000' },
    { title: 'Reroute to Remain', release: '2002' }
];

pluck(albums, 'title');  // => ['Colony', 'Clayman', 'Reroute to Remain']
```

In your specific case, it would look something like this:

```
var valueMapper = function (key) {
    return users.map(function (user) {
        return user[key];
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to build a `hash` table that will look like:

`{
key1: Array('all values of key1'),
key2: Array('all values of key2'),
...}`

Then use this hash table to get result quickly. this will be good solution since you need to build the hash once and then the result can be retrieved with complexity of `O(1)`.

See example below:

```js
var users = [
  {firstName: 'Pete', lastName: 'Barrat', favoriteFood: 'Pizza', age: 30},
  {firstName: 'Lisa', lastName: 'Jenkins', favoriteFood: 'Curry', age: 34},
  {firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Yates', favoriteFood: 'Fish', age: 54},
  {firstName: 'Claire', lastName: 'Smith', favoriteFood: 'Steak', age: 21},
  {firstName: 'Adam', lastName: 'Johnson', favoriteFood: 'Pasta', age: 27}
 ]
var hash = {};

users.forEach((user) => {
  Object.keys(user).forEach((key) => {
    hash[key] = hash[key] || new Array();
    hash[key].push(user[key]);
  })
});

function getKey(key) {
  return hash[key] || [];
}

console.log(getKey('age'));
console.log(getKey('favoriteFood'));
console.log(getKey('hey'));
```